# equally distribute objects using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data as follows

```
|Fruit   |Numbers|
|Apples  |     50|
|Banana  |     30|
|Oranges |     20|
|Grapes  |    100|
|Peach   |     30|
|Kiwi    |     70|
```

I need to re-arrange them 3 bags in such a way that I have 3 bags of equal(or almost) number of fruits using NTILE. Could you please help?

Output should be like

```
|Bag_id|Contents        |Count
|Bag 1 | Apples,Oranges,Peaches|100|
|Bag 2 | Kiwi,Banana    |100|
|Bag 3 |Grapes|100|
```

Comment: Why does it have to use ntile?  Does it have to give that exact result?  If you need that exact result, what algorithm was used?  If you are able to use other algorithms, what are your constraints?

Comment: How does your output meet the condition of almost equal number of fruits?

Comment: I'm basically looking for a solution now, NTILE is not a must. But would love to see it using NTILE

Comment: @GordonLinoff : its just a representation, I just need average of all the bags to be same, like Bag 1 - 200, Bag 2 - 195, Bag 3 - 201

Comment: You bags have 240, 270, 230 items.  A simpler (and better, in this case) packing would be 240, 250, 250...  (order items ascending, then bag them into bags 1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,2,1,etc)

Comment: I just changed the counts, so that the counts match. 
Please forgive me, this is my first post!

Comment: Your new data has bag sizes 150, 100, 100.  It is possible to get 130, 110, 110 (I'm not attacking you, this problem has many imperfect solutions, we're just trying to ascertain your Exact requirements)

Comment: This is not a SQL problem (not much of one anyway); it is an algorithm problem. What you have is a very simple example of "load balancing" and for a small sample like you have it can be solved by considering all the possible combinations and giving each a "score" (which you haven't defined, but let's say it's the variance of the resulting set of three numbers) and picking the one with the lowest score. The general problem, however, is exceptionally hard and you need to specify what will be a "good enough answer".

Comment: And the difficulty is the math problem, before you think about any code (or even what programming language to use for the solution, be it SQL or anything else).

Comment: @MatBailie, thank you. I have changed the count again, I will keep in mind that I have to be really specific.
mathguy : I am trying to re-do a auto generated query with a new SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  i.*,
  CASE WHEN item <= 3 THEN item ELSE 7 - item END  AS bag
FROM
(
  SELECT
    b.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY batch, ORDER BY numbers) AS item
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      t.*,
      NTILE(6) OVER (ORDER BY numbers) AS batch
    FROM
      your_table t
  )
    b
)
  i
```

I'm on my phone, so I won't add the bit done by Gordon to concatenate the items in to a single row.

But this implements a Very simple bagging algorithm.

It happens to be Fairly good when you have 6 items to put in 3 bags.

It happens to be Awful when you have 4 items to put in 3 bags.

And it doesn't really cope with large amount of small numbers and a small amount of large numbers.

There are many algorithms for you to Google, and pick you preference.

But it's an example, using NTILE...

Comment: Case in point about what your constrains are.  This Perfectly solved your second version of the question, but failed to find the best solution to your third version of the question.  There isn't actually a solution that always works perfectly without analysing Every possible combination.  Other algorithms (such as this one) are faster, but are mere approximations.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want two fruits in each basket (ignoring the `numbers` column), then you can use `ntile()`:

```
select 'Bag ' || tercile,
       listagg(Fruit, ',') over (within group order by Fruit) as fruits
from (select t.*,
             ntile(3) over (order by numbers) as tercile
      from t
     ) t
group by tercile;
```

As with your sample results, the sum of `numbers` is not even approximately equal across the baskets.

Answer (score 0):

I had ~300 fruits, so based on @MatBailie, I found the soln.

Thank you all!!

SELECT **Wm_concat**(fruit),

       bag

FROM   (SELECT i.*,

               CASE

                 WHEN item <= 10 THEN item

                 ELSE 10 - item

               END AS bag

        FROM   (SELECT b.*,

                       **Row_number**()

                         OVER (

                           partition BY batch

                           ORDER BY cnt) AS item

                FROM   (SELECT t.*,

                               **Ntile**(50)

                                 OVER (

                                   ORDER BY cnt) AS batch

                        FROM   tmp t) b) i)

GROUP  BY bag;

Comment: You have `NTILE(50)`, implying 25 bags?  But then you should have `<= 25` and `51 - item`...  Also, you should upvote and or accept answers that helped you.